# I have created a no of sprites and added them to the scene with the same reference and now, how can i remove them with out using tags?

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, cross-platform, cocos2d-x, sprite

I have created a no of sprites and added them to the scene with the same name.

Now, i want to remove all those, even the ones with out any reference. How can i achieve that.

With out using `removeChildBytag();` or without using tags.

```
void Science::onBallMovement(cocos2d::Ref* pSender){

auto sp = (Sprite*)pSender;

v1 = sp->getPosition();


if (v1 == v2) {
    return;
}

if(v1!=v2) {

    if (sp->getTag()==1) {
       s = Sprite::create("Dot.png");
    }
    if (sp->getTag()==2) {
        s = Sprite::create("BlueDot.png");
    }

    s->setPosition(v1);
    s->autorelease();
    this->addChild(s);
}
v2 = v1;
}

void Science::update(float delta){

if (setting) {
    this->onBallMovement(spr);
    this->onBallMovement(spr1);
}
}
```

By overriding the update method of node class, i am calling the above repeatedly and based on the current position of my sprite which moves randomly, i am creating a tracker of path. But now, i want to remove it based on the user selection, how can i do it?

Comment: uncertain about c++, but here is how i would do this in obj-c. I would just remove the container node when logic requires it, and in it's `onExit` method, i would iterate all its children and remove them from parent, with cleanup.

Comment: for example in objective-c.

for (int i =0; i<10; i++){

Comment: for example in objective-c.

for (int i =0; i<10; i++){
Box *box1 = [[Box alloc]init]; 
}

[box1 release];

if i write code something like this in obj-c. Then, how can i make sure that all objects are removed. Usually it removes only the latest one, where as the others are unreferenced.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, so i am going the explain the most easiest way:

**Initialising a global node and remove all children**

> Declare a node in the .h file of your class.

```
Node* _spriteParent;
```

> Now define the node in the init method of your class.

```
_spriteParent = Node::create();
_spriteParent->setPosition(Vec2::ZERO);
this->addchild(_spriteParent);
```

> Now whenever you are creating the sprite, just add that sprite to the
>   above node, which you have just created(do not call autorelease on the
>   sprite).

```
_spriteParent->addChild(s);
```

When you want to remove all the sprites that you have added to the _spriteParent, call this method:

```
_spriteParent->removeAllChildren();
```

and you are done. Hope it helps.

Comment: Some what ok. It is just trying to do it in another style like adding all those objects to an array and then removing it. But, what i want is, how to remove all those unreferenced objects.